# Is there an actual armor to craft after completing Hermes' Task Board?

Tags: immortals-fenyx-rising

I've already collected all *Mythical*, *Molten* and *Midnight* fragments, and their description states that after completing every Hermes' Task all fragments can be merged to craft a wonderful armor.

Ok, I did it. How to get that armor? The only things I obtained after completing each task were armor **skins**, which is NOT a wonderful armor at all. Also because I still have the fragments in my inventory.

Is there any final armor to craft or does my prize consist only in lousy skins?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [IGN](https://www.ign.com/wikis/immortals-fenyx-rising/Armor_Locations), I already own every existing armor.

And to answer my question:

> The Ultimate Armors are earned via unconventional means compared to most sets: three of them **are only awarded for completing Heroic Tasks at Hermes’s Heroic Tasks Board** at the Hall of the Gods, and the golden version is unlocked first rather than last.

So these armor skins are actually the reward for completing those tasks. I don't understand why I still have the fragments in my inventory, but there isn't any secret armor to craft with them, as of now.

[image]